# console shows phaser 3.11 but dependency is 3.23

Tags: phaser-framework

Here are my dependencies in package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
"electron": "^7.1.6",
"http-server": "^0.12.1",
"phaser": "^3.23.0"
  },
```

This is what's shown in the browser:

[image]

I'm unable to use Phaser.Scale, and sys.install for plugins. Any help in upgrading to 3.16+ would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Do you have a repository to share to better understand the error?

Maybe you have two imports, one in package.json and one directly in index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you don't have some script tag that loads the v3.11 in your `index.html`, like this one

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.11.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

I've been able to reproduce your error only by using the script tag, and by avoiding all `import 'phaser'` in javascript files.